# PHP MYSQL To JSON & Array Categories

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, algorithm

*Hello, I'm having trouble creating an algorithm to create a JSON output from a MySQL database using PHP.*

**I require a JSON output with this structure using arrays, mysql, loops.**

```
{
"emails": [
    {
        "group": "Today April 23",
        "list": [{
            "id": 1,
            "subject": "Pages - Multi-Purpose Admin Template Revolution Begins here!",
            "to": ["David Nester", "Jane Smith"],
            "body": "<p>First email body</p> ",
            "time": "5 Mins ago",
            "datetime": "Today at 1:33pm",
            "from": "David Nester",
            "dp": "assets/img/profiles/avatar.jpg",
            "dpRetina": "assets/img/profiles/avatar2x.jpg"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "subject": "Your site has some very imaginative animation /movement! ",
            "to": ["Anne Simons"],
            "body": "<p>Second email body</p> ",
            "time": "45 mins ago",
            "datetime": "Today at 1:33pm",
            "from": "Anne Simons",
            "dp": "assets/img/profiles/5.jpg",
            "dpRetina": "assets/img/profiles/5x.jpg"
        }]
    }, {
        "group": "Yesterday April 22",
        "list": [{
            "id": 3,
            "subject": "Good design is obvious. Great design is transparent",
            "to": ["John Doe", "Anne Simons"],
            "body": "<p>Third email body</p> ",
            "time": "1:33pm",
            "datetime": "Today at 1:33pm",
            "from": "David Nester",
            "dp": "assets/img/profiles/b.jpg",
            "dpRetina": "assets/img/profiles/b2x.jpg"
        }]
    }
]
```

}

Well so far this is what I have been able to come up with in PHP.

```
<?php
      header('Content-type: application/json');

      // Start session and get session values.
      session_start();

      // Connect to database.
      require('../../config/database.php');

      $sql   = "SELECT DISTINCT(`datetime`) FROM `memo`";
      $dates = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

      foreach ($dates as $key => $date) {
                $sql     = "SELECT `memo`.*, `users`.`username` FROM `memo` JOIN `users` ON `memo`.`to` = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "' WHERE `datetime` = '" . $date['datetime'] . "'";
                $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                // Clean array for each new loop.
                unset($lists);

                // Loop and create lists.
                foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
                          $lists[] = array(
                                    'id' => $result['id'],
                                    'subject' => $result['subject'],
                                    'to' => array(
                                              $result['username']
                                    ),
                                    'body' => $result['body'],
                                    'time' => $result['time'],
                                    'datetime' => $result['datetime'],
                                    'from' => $result['username'],
                                    'dp' => "../assets/img/profiles/3.jpg",
                                    'dpRetina' => "../assets/img/profiles/3x.jpg"
                          );
                }

                // Set group variable to date.                  
                $group = date("M d", strtotime($date['datetime']));

                // Current date.
                $current_date = date("M d");

                // User interface recent date into simple text like "Today, April 24".  
                if ($group == $current_date) {
                          $group = "Today, " . date("M d");
                }

                // Add group and list to email array.                 
                $json[] = array(
                          'group' => $group,
                          'list' => $lists
                );
      }

      $memos = array(
                'emails' => $json
      );
      echo json_encode($memos);

      // Close connection.
      mysqli_close($conn);
     ?>
```

This is my current output.
Each array repeats itself before the next list item.

```
{

"emails": [
    {
        "group": "Today, Jun 05",
        "list": [
            {
                "id": "7",
                "subject": "Subject Text",
                "to": [
                    "admin"
                ],
                "body": "This is sample text! <br>",
                "time": "15:02:46",
                "datetime": "2016-06-05",
                "from": "admin",
                "dp": "../assets/img/profiles/3.jpg",
                "dpRetina": "../assets/img/profiles/3x.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": "7",
                "subject": "Subject Text",
                "to": [
                    "edem"
                ],
                "body": "This is sample text! <br>",
                "time": "15:02:46",
                "datetime": "2016-06-05",
                "from": "edem",
                "dp": "../assets/img/profiles/3.jpg",
                "dpRetina": "../assets/img/profiles/3x.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": "8",
                "subject": "Subject Text 2",
                "to": [
                    "admin"
                ],
                "body": "This is sample text!&nbsp; 2<br>",
                "time": "15:02:55",
                "datetime": "2016-06-05",
                "from": "admin",
                "dp": "../assets/img/profiles/3.jpg",
                "dpRetina": "../assets/img/profiles/3x.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": "8",
                "subject": "Subject Text 2",
                "to": [
                    "edem"
                ],
                "body": "This is sample text!&nbsp; 2<br>",
                "time": "15:02:55",
                "datetime": "2016-06-05",
                "from": "edem",
                "dp": "../assets/img/profiles/3.jpg",
                "dpRetina": "../assets/img/profiles/3x.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": "9",
                "subject": "Subject Text 3",
                "to": [
                    "admin"
                ],
                "body": "This is sample text!&nbsp; 3<br>",
                "time": "15:03:01",
                "datetime": "2016-06-05",
                "from": "admin",
                "dp": "../assets/img/profiles/3.jpg",
                "dpRetina": "../assets/img/profiles/3x.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": "9",
                "subject": "Subject Text 3",
                "to": [
                    "edem"
                ],
                "body": "This is sample text!&nbsp; 3<br>",
                "time": "15:03:01",
                "datetime": "2016-06-05",
                "from": "edem",
                "dp": "../assets/img/profiles/3.jpg",
                "dpRetina": "../assets/img/profiles/3x.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
]

}
```

Comment: What are you currently getting into the console?

Comment: What is it that is not working? Do you get an error or is your output different then expected?

Comment: @Alfred_P My output is different than expected. I have added my current output.